# Xcode - typing really slow as well as animations moving diagonally down screen really slowly

Tags: xcode

I've been using Xcode and i don't know whats going on when i type in a text field it feels as if its lagging and when a UIAlertView Pops up a grey background is overplayed but some reason how it is appearing on screen is that it moves diagonally from the top right and it moves slowly. 
Help would be much appreciated :D

Comment: can you take some screenshots? its hard to imagine what exactly is going on

Comment: Here they are : http://imgur.com/dgsT191
http://imgur.com/8m67D7V
basically it feels really really laggy the whole animations are laggy. The picture of the alert box does move into position but really laggy. I guess it's smooth but moving slowly so I guess laggy isn't the best term to describe it. Thanks

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean. On your iPhone, not in Xcode. In Xcode, on the left side, go to the 6th tab while the app is running on your iPhone. There should be information about CPU usage, RAM, FPS etc. take a screenshot of that an post it please.

Comment: heres a link :D http://imgur.com/TGhluA0

Comment: oh gosh you're a hard nut to crack, I guess you already restarted your iPhone?

Comment: yeah I've used the iPhone simulator and the problem is still there :/ the thing is it worked the other day perfectly fine but some reason all the animations for textfields etc. is being really slow

Comment: Hm, how much work did you put in there yet? Because I guess your project is broken. If I was you I'd create a new project and do everything again assuming it will work. (You're able to copy the code so it shouldn't be too bad depending on how much you do by code if course)

Comment: Okay yeah the project is only like 4 view controllers so I'll try it out on another project thanks :)